# Where can I find performance report of Titan graph database, or its successor Janusgraph?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, janusgraph

I am doing survey for Titan graph database, and now I'd like to know its performance.

Ideally, I want a report that tells the time consumption for several different queries, with different settings of the edge count and vertex count of the underlying graph. Additionally, the similar report under concurrent scenario is also needed.

Does anyone has done performance tests like these before? I guess the developers of Titan might, but I searched for nothing. Where can I get the performance report like these? Or to whom should I ask for help?

Comment: http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/doc/titan-stress-poster.pdf

Comment: OMG how do you find this pdf.. it really helps a lot..

Comment: It's in the titan official documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some of them from the titan official documentation

[Titan: A Highly Scalable, Distributed Graph Database (poster)](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/doc/titan-stress-poster.pdf): A presentation of an initial stress test evaluation of Titan using real Twitter network data. (July 2012, presented at GraphLab 2012 conference)

[Educating the Planet with Pearson Education](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/educating-the-planet-with-pearson): Presents a large-scale benchmark of Titan with a 121 billion edge graph. (May 2013, in collaboration with Pearson Education)

Source : http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/related-links.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently, ignoring appendices is a really bad habit..

Answer (score 3):

Quoting my own answer on the [`janusgraph-users@` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-users/wEFJU4FQIKc/lTY4fRuIAgAJ) in response to the same question:

> https://github.com/socialsensor/graphdb-benchmarks has some results for various graph databases, including Titan, but that framework does not support JanusGraph so it is not represented in that list. If you're interested in adapting this framework to support JanusGraph, please go ahead! I filed [this feature request](https://github.com/socialsensor/graphdb-benchmarks/issues/24), but it hasn't gotten any attention so far.
>
> More recently, the company behind TigerGraph compared their database to Neo4j and Titan (but again, not JanusGraph); and published [their results](http://doc.tigergraph.com/report/WP_NPGbenchmark_Sep17_web.pdf). You may want to contact them and recreate their benchmark on JanusGraph if you're interested.
>
> CyberAgent also published results for their benchmark of [JanusGraph vs. OrientDB](https://adtech.cyberagent.io/techblog/archives/2980) (in Japanese) which may be of interest.